# How to get an average of timestamps? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am currently using this:

```
select avg(tank_level)
from (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, tank_level
    from data_tanksensor
    where sensors_on_site_id = 91
) s
group by (rn + ((Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)-1))/ (Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)
;
```

To get 10 averages from a table. This table also has timestamps that I would like to get the average timestamp for each of the 10 average tank_level. This is being used to create a history graph. If anyone can help me modify this query to also get average timestamps that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The table looks like this

`.  id       sensors_on_site_id      tank_level           timestamps
[PK] bigint     integer           double precision   time without time zone
...........  ..................   ................   ......................
12345          91                   7.5          2017-03-24 11:16:31.143362
12346          91                   7.6          2017-03-24 11:21:31.148639
12347          91                   5.4          2017-03-24 11:26:31.155739
12348          91                   3.6          2017-03-24 11:31:31.156478
12349          91                   8.5          2017-03-24 11:36:31.157303
12350          91                   4.2          2017-03-24 11:41:31.172008`

And for example if I only want to averages from this my original query would be

`select avg(tank_level)
    from (
        select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, tank_level
        from data_tanksensor
        where sensors_on_site_id = 91
    ) s
    group by (rn + ((Select count(*)/2 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)-1))/ (Select count(*)/2 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)
    ;`

of coarse the query is missing the portion that would avg the timestamp which is what I'm trying to figure out. But the expected results that I'm trying to get would be

`avg                   timestamp
double precision       timestamp without time zone
................       ...........................
6.833333                2017-03-24 11:21:31...
5.433333                2017-03-24 11:36:31...`

Again this is just sample data, the amount of rows that are being averaged are hundreds at a time. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: F.ex. `to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch from timestamp_col)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select to_timestamp(avg(timestamps)) "timestamps", avg(tank_level) "TankLevel"
from (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, tank_level, extract(epoch from timestamps) "timestamps"
    from data_tanksensor
    where sensors_on_site_id = 91
) s
group by (rn + ((Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)-1))/ (Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where sensors_on_site_id = 91)
order by timestamps asc
;`

Figured it out
Thank you all for your examples

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your timestamps to unix timestamps, sum the values, divide by the number of values and convert back to a timestamp. A quick working example:

```
with
    __ts as(
        select unnest(array[
            '2015-11-22 09:31:00', '2015-11-22 09:32:00', '2015-11-23 11:31:00', '2015-11-23 11:32:00',
            '2015-11-23 11:34:00', '2015-11-23 15:28:00', '2015-11-23 15:29:00', '2015-11-24 10:49:00',
            '2015-11-24 10:50:00', '2015-11-24 11:18:00'
        ]::timestamp without time zone[]) as ts
    )
select
    to_timestamp(sum(extract(epoch from ts)) / (select count(1) from __ts))
from
    __ts
```

Comment: Unix timestamps (aka. `double precision`) can be averaged (`avg()`) directly, there is no need to calculate `sum() / count()` manually (especially, because `count()` can return zero, so the equivalent would be the -- more cumbersome -- `sum() / nullif(count(), 0)`)

Comment: @pozs yes, that's pretty derpy of me there. Good catch